# No query results for model [App\Operator] and [App/Nurse]. Laravel redirect error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is a login function where the user is logged in according to their user role.

Case 1 and case 2 statements are working correctly where the user is logged into the  admin and a doctor dashboard respectively.

The case 3 statement is for nurses where they are logged in to their own dashboard but i keep getting an error:

> "No query results for model [App\Nurse]."

when it is redirecting to the dashboard, as the operator dashboard.

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [

        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'

    ]);

   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
       $user=User::whereRaw('email=?',[Input::get('email')])->first();

       if($user!=null){
           switch($user->role_id){
               case 1:
                   if($user->status==0){
                       session()->flash('flash_message_error', ' Your Account has been  deactivated. Contact the administrator');
                       return Redirect::to('admin/login');
                   }
                   return redirect()->route("index");
               break;

               case 2:
                   $doctor=Doctor::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
                   if($user->status==0){
                       session()->flash('flash_message_error', 'Your Account has been deactivated. Contact the administrator');
                       return Redirect::to('admin/login');
                   }
                   return redirect()->route("dashboard")->with(compact('doctor'));
               break;

               case 3:
                   $nur=Nurse::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
                   if($user->status==0){
                       session()->flash('flash_message_error', 'Your Account has been deactivated. Contact the administrator');
                       return Redirect::to('admin/login');
                   }
                   return redirect()->route("NurseDashboard")->with(compact('nur'));
                   break;


               case 7:
                   $opt = Operate::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
                   if($user->status==0){
                       session()->flash('flash_message_error', 'Your Account has been deactivated. Contact the administrator');
                       return Redirect::to('admin/login');
                   }
                   return redirect()->route("OperatorDashboard")->with(compact('opt'));

           }
       }
   }
    session()->flash('flash_message_error', 'Incorrect Username/password Combination');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of dashboard controller methods

Comment: I later got it work but am having a little challenge now. I want to do a search on a list of doctors form a view doctors link and i have no idea on how to start